# Maven compilation TimeOut error

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, repository

I need to compile with a prod maven profile, so I execute the command:

```
mvnw package -Pprod  -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

But it gives me a `Connection TimeOut` error:

```
C:\Users\UserX\Desktop\Workspace\mecenz>mvnw package -Pprod  -Dmaven.test.skip=tru
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.3.9/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.downloadInternal(DefaultDownloader.java:73)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.download(DefaultDownloader.java:60)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.createDist(Installer.java:64)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
```

Here I have configured the proxy as it should be in the `settings.xml` of maven:

```
<proxies>
<proxy>    
  <id>the_id</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
    <!--  <username>proxyuser</username>
    <password>proxypass</password>-->
  <host>my proxy adresse</host>
  <port>8080</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
</proxies>
```

I really don't know what should I do more!

I have changed this URL in `maven-wrraper.properties` into:
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.3.9/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip and yet gives me the same error.

How would you troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set your `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables to the same value as the one set in your settings.xml, and download maven yourself, without having to rely on an [`mvnw` maven wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper) (presented [in this article](http://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/11/maven-wrapper-example/))

Simply fo to the [Downloading Apache Maven 3.5.0](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) page, and get the Binary zip archive that you can uncompress anywhere you want. Add that folder to your PATH and you are set to use a regular `mvn` command.

Comment: Thank you so much for your respons, it seems the best way... now where to put the bin in ".m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin" ?

Comment: @Smahane if you are just using maven (and not the wrapper which puts maven here: https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/11/maven-wrapper-example/#crayon-59086475645b8480906122-3), you can uncompress http://apache.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.0-bin.zip anywhere you want.

Comment: I already have maven installed and configured, i don't understand why i need to uncompress it again ...

Comment: @Smahane you can use the one installed by the wrapper, but the all point of my answer is to not use the wrapper at all, hence my proposition to download and uncompress maven anywhere you want.

Comment: yes i understood your proposition (not to use the wrraper), my question is why download maven and decompress it? knowing that my project is a maven project and i already have maven decompressed and mentioned in my "Environnement variables"

Comment: In that case, you don't have to download it, as long as the mvn command does work.

Comment: amazing ! it works perfectly .. thank you soooo much :)